# Getting ORA-00001 unique constraint violated error when calling a trigger

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
create or replace TRIGGER "DB"."TRIG_PERIOD_TRUANCY_INS_UPD" 
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT
ON AT_PERIOD_ATTENDANCE_RECORDS
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF UPDATING THEN
    delete at_period_truancy where period_attendance_records_id = :old.period_attendance_records_id;
  END IF;

    insert into at_period_truancy (period_attendance_records_id, district_number, school_id, student_id, calendar_date, school_year, minutes)
    select :new.period_attendance_records_id, :new.district_number, :new.school_id, :new.student_id, :new.calendar_date, :new.school_year,
           (case when :new.attendance_status = 'A' then period.end_time - period.begin_time
               when coalesce(:new.tardy_time_in_time, period.begin_time) - period.begin_time >
                    period.end_time - coalesce(:new.tardy_time_out_time, period.end_time)
               then coalesce(:new.tardy_time_in_time, period.begin_time) - period.begin_time
               else period.end_time - coalesce(:new.tardy_time_out_time, period.end_time) end)*24*60
    from ca_calendar cal
         inner join ca_school_calendar calendar
         on (cal.district_number = calendar.district_number
             and cal.calendar_id = calendar.calendar_id )
         inner join sc_class_meeting_pattern meeting
         on (calendar.cycle_day_cd = meeting.cycle_day_cd)
         inner join sc_class class
         on (class.school_scheduling_param_id = meeting.school_scheduling_param_id
             and class.class_id = meeting.class_id)
         inner join sc_period_info period
         on (meeting.school_scheduling_param_id = period.school_scheduling_param_id
             and meeting.period = period.period)
   where :new.district_number = cal.district_number
     and cal.is_active_ind = 1
     and :new.school_id = cal.school_id
     and :new.school_year = cal.school_year
     and :new.calendar_type_cd = cal.calendar_type_cd
     and :new.track_number = cal.track_number
     and :new.calendar_date = calendar.calendar_date
     and :new.school_id = class.school_id
     and :new.class_id = class.class_id
     and 1 in (select use_in_truancy_report_ind
                 from enum_at_absence_reason_code
                where district_number = :new.district_number
                  and school_id = :new.school_id
                  and value = :new.absence_reason_code
               union all
               select use_in_truancy_report_ind
                 from enum_at_tardy_reason_code
                where district_number = :new.district_number
                  and school_id = :new.school_id
                  and value = :new.tardy_reason_code);
END TRIG_PERIOD_TRUANCY_INS_UPD;
```

This is the trigger that I am using. When calling the update statement this trigger is getting invoked and when I pass tardy_reason_code as UN this error is happening. It executes without any issues if I pass  tardy_reason_code with different values.

Comment: Please, provide [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Join of 7 tables doesn't look like what is really required to demonstrate an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger is inserting into `at_period_truancy` tables.

As Oracle raises `ORA-00001` (unique constraint violated), it means that you're trying to insert primary key value which already exists in the table.

You didn't post `create table` statement so it is difficult to guess which columns make the primary key, but - you should know it so check which values you already have in there, compare that to values currently being inserted and you'll know what to do.

Maybe you'll have to modify primary key (add other columns? Abandon idea of current primary key and using a sequence (or identity column)) or the way you're inserting values into the table.